# How to restore purchase from multiple google play store?

Tags: google-play-store, paid-apps

I have multiple account logged in my google play store and I have different app purchased from different account. My all purchase from one account got restored(the one which who logged in first in my play store) and unable to restore the other app purchase . When I try to restore the purchase of app I get purchasing option from another account other than from the account purchased earlier.

Comment: How did you restore? Is it  Google restore on a fresh install?

Comment: [Is the other account from which you purchased synced? Check your account settings](https://www.77sparx.com/restoring-google-play-purchases-onto-device-different-account/)

Comment: @beeshyams reinstalling after factory reset. I will try the second one will tell you.

Comment: Were you able to check? If it worked, please self answer the question